# Isopropyl Alcohol Vs Acetone for Dissolving Organic Contaminants on PCB

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, cleaning

Acetone is widely used in the labs as a solvent to clean the vials and tubes as it is good solvent for organic materials. While Isopropyl alcohol is used as a rubbing alcohol for cleaning contaminants on the body before injection. Both are good solvents for organic materials. I would like to know which one is more suitable for cleaning the organic contaminants on the PCB's (Printed Circuit Board) with minimal residue?

Comment: Depends if there are plastics attacked by acetone, e.g. polystyrene.

Comment: PCB should be OK, but a soldered PCB has *components*, e.g. polystyrene caps, or a piezo element in a polystyrene case.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I see, make so much sense! I didnt know that there are polystyrene caps. I guess isopropyl alcohol or ethanol is the best alternative then. The reason I asked this question is I tried to use medical isopropyl alcohol swabs to clean my phone screen, I saw residue left over the screen, despite the claim that isopropyl alcohol doesn't leave residue.

Comment: The residue may be oils left behind that the iso missed... but I certainly wouldn't use a stronger solvent on a phone. Just gentle rubbing with microfiber cloth will remove most oils.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik +1 makes so much sense. I did it on the screen to see if residue is left or not because its hard to check on the PCB. Allright, I guess you answered my question. Acetone isnt recommended for PCB's where as Isopropyl can be used instead.

Comment: Acetone aggressively attacks many polymeric components (not just polystyrene) and often completely destroys them. The circuit board itself, for example, may well be damaged as will many electronic components. isopropanol does not and is always a better choice.

Comment: @matt_black makes sense. just curious: can isopropanol and ethanol be used interchangeably for cleaning circuit board in your opinion.

Comment: @gfdsal yes. But pure dry ethanol in not readily available and comes with legal restrictions. Pure Isopropanol is easier to get and it is easier to dry and doesn’t need to be denatured to stop people drinking it.

Comment: @matt_black +1 I believe you made it easier for me to decide what to purchase. I had an option of ethanol or isopropanol 70%, I shall go with isopropanol as pharmacy ethanol is most likely to have ingredients that denatures it and might leave residue on the circuit board which is undesirable.

Comment: "Rubbing alcohol" is 70% IPA, you should use 99% for cleaning. FWIW I found that by "upgrading" to acetone for cleaning BARE boards before etching improved the adhesion of the photoresist, which allowed me to do higher resolution etches. But this is bare boards, nothing to damage really at this stage.